How do I reformulate this max GMV ratio constraint in convex way?
Assuming I have N stocks. I want to have the following constraint in my optimization problem setup.
$|x_i| \le \alpha \sum_{j}^N |x_j|$ where $\alpha$ is known, say 0.6. The intuition here is the GMV of every optimized stock can't be more than $\alpha$ of the optimized overall GMV, to achieve a more diversified portfolio.
Assuming N = 3, then we have:
$|x_0| \le 0.6 (|x_0| + |x_1| + |x_2|)$
$|x_1| \le 0.6 (|x_0| + |x_1| + |x_2|)$
$|x_2| \le 0.6 (|x_0| + |x_1| + |x_2|)$
How do I re-formulate this in a convex way? The solve I'm using is Mosek.
Thanks!

This isn't technically an answer, because I can't immediately observe if what you are trying to do is achieveable but, since $\alpha$ seems somewhat subjective in your query would you consider readjusting this subjectivity:
$ \alpha_1 \sum_i |x_i| \approx \alpha_2 ||\mathbf{x}||_2 $
Then you solve this with SOCP.

Thanks. Can you elaborate on how to solve $\alpha_1 \sum_i |x_i|  \approx \alpha_2 || x||_{2}$ in SOCP?
Following the thoughts, what about if the constraint is changed to:
$x_i^2 \le \alpha \sum_{j}^N x_j^2$
Is there a way to reformulate this one?

The closest I have come so far is to engineer a the constraint into a quadratically constrained quadratic program (QCQP):

where in your case, $q_i=0$ and $r_i=0$ and,
$ 
P_i = \mathbf{I} - \alpha \mathbf{1}
$ (where $\mathbf{1}$ is a matrix of ones)
I am assuming that your objective function is probably quaudratic as well according to most portfolio optimization problems.
